# Handling checkbox checks in a foreach loop from a cross-reference table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, foreach

I have three MySQL tables and one is a cross reference table:

```
-----------------------------------

Table name: resources
id
resource

-----------------------------------

Table name: companies
id
company

-----------------------------------

Table name: res_co_xref
res_id
co_id

-----------------------------------
```

I can join them successfully with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM res_co_xref LEFT JOIN companies ON (companies.id = res_co_xref.co_id) WHERE res_co_xref.res_id=1
```

The result:

```
res_id      co_id
1               12
1               13
1               16
```

There are 10 companies, only 3 should be checked for this particular resource.

Here is my problem code which currently contains a nested loop... The result is three checkboxes per row.

```
<?php foreach ($companyrow as $rowco):?> // this is coming from a PHP class
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rowco->company ?></td>
        <td>

        <?php foreach ($rescorow as $rescorowloop):?> // this is from another PHP class

        <div class="sel">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <?php if($rowco->id == $rescorowloop->co_id): ?> // here I successfully checkmark the correct company but there are three checkboxes
              <input type="checkbox" name="company_id[]" value="<?php echo $rowco->id; ?>" checked="checked" />
              <?php  else: ?>
              <input type="checkbox" name="company_id[]" value="<?php echo $rowco->id; ?>" />
              <?php endif; ?>
            </label>
          </div>

          <?php endforeach;?>
          <?php unset($rescorowloop);?>

          </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
      <?php unset($rowco);?>
```

How would you go about handling this? Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally i will do:

```
 foreach ($thing as $key => $value)
 {

  if ($value == "something that needs to be checked")
  { 
     $chk = "checked='checked'";
  }
  else
  {
     $chk = "";
  }
  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='name' id='id' " . $chk . ">";
}
```

that what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried implementing your code and could not get it to work with my xref table... I pretty much end up with the same issue e.g. a nested loop that displays three checkboxes on each row.

Comment: Actually, your code did help! I had to reposition the foreach statement and then add a "break;" after $chk = "checked='checked'"; Then I placed the "echo" outside of the foreach statement.... Thanks a lot for getting me on the right path with this one!